# Unable to compile my android app with "google-play-services"

Tags: android, gradle, mixpanel

I am trying to incorporate MixPanel in my Android application it requried google-play-services to the included as well. I added the following lines to my **build.gradle**

```
compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.6.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
```

I get the following error when I run **$ gradle build --daemon**

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'git'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         http://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven/com/google/android/gms/play-services/7.8.0/play-services-7.8.0.pom
         http://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven/com/google/android/gms/play-services/7.8.0/play-services-7.8.0.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services/7.8.0/play-services-7.8.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services/7.8.0/play-services-7.8.0.jar
         file:/home/prakash/Programming/Android/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/7.8.0/play-services-7.8.0.pom
         file:/home/prakash/Programming/Android/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/7.8.0/play-services-7.8.0.jar
     Required by:
         :git:unspecified

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Any idea what the issue is ?

Comment: Do you have google play services downloaded in your SDK?

Comment: put `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0'` in your global gradle.build buildscript `dependencies` block and add plugin to your module (`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services').
Also, check if you have services sdk (look it up in SDK Manager)

Comment: Update your sdk manager. @invariant it is not required.

Answer (score 1):

All I needed to do was install

```
Google Play Services
Google Respository
```

through my **Android SDK Manager"

Thanks @mateus @invariant @gabriele

Answer (score 0):

You almost never will need all play services API.
Take a look into this list and compile just what you really need.
[Google Play Services APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split)